# Combinar dos listas serializadas para que una dependan de la otra, C#

Tags: c#, html, lista, serialización

tengo este problema con un programa que estoy haciendo, el objetivo es después de haber registrado varios ciclistas en el programa y haber guardado sus datos, registrar actividades a estos ciclistas y que cada actividad pertenezca a un solo ciclista y luego poder tener la opción de exportar el ciclista con sus actividades en un archivo html. Dejare el código completo de los menúes, esta resaltado el case "1" de la agregación de actividades y la exportación en html. Gracias

```
    public static void Main(){

        manejadorCiclistas mC = new manejadorCiclistas();
        manejadorActividades mA = new manejadorActividades();

        bool contiprograma = true;
        string seleccion = "";
        List<Ciclista> All = null;
        List<Actividad> todo = null;





        while(contiprograma)
        {

         Console.Clear();
         Console.WriteLine("Programa que guarda datos de Ciclistas. (Cantidad de Ciclistas "+mC.totalciclis()+")"+ "  (Cantidad de Actividades "+mA.totalactis()+")");
         Console.WriteLine();

         Console.WriteLine("1. Gestionar Ciclistas");
         Console.WriteLine("2. Gestionar Actividades");
         Console.WriteLine("3. Reportes");
         Console.WriteLine("4. Salir");
         Console.WriteLine();

         Console.Write("Seleccione la opcion deseada: ");
         seleccion = Console.ReadLine();

         switch(seleccion)
            {

             case "1": 

             bool contiprograma2 = true;

             while(contiprograma2)
                {

                  Console.Clear();
                  Console.WriteLine("Gestion de Ciclistas");
                  Console.WriteLine();
                  Console.WriteLine("1. Agregar Ciclistas");
                  Console.WriteLine("2. Modificar Ciclistas");
                  Console.WriteLine("3. Eliminar Ciclistas");
                  Console.WriteLine("4. Volver a Menu Principal ");
                  Console.WriteLine();

                  Console.Write("Seleccione la opcion deseada: ");
                  seleccion = Console.ReadLine();

                  switch(seleccion)
                    {
                        case "1": 


                          Ciclista cicli = new Ciclista();
                          Console.Clear();

                          Console.WriteLine("Agregar Nuevo Ciclista");
                          Console.WriteLine();

                          Console.Write("Ingrese la Cedula: ");
                          cicli.cedula = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Nombre: ");
                          cicli.nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Apellido: ");
                          cicli.apellido = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese su Dia de nacimiento: ");
                          int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cicli.dia);
                          Console.Write("Ingrese su Mes de nacimiento: ");
                          int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out cicli.mes);
                          Console.Write("Ingrese su Anio de nacimiento: ");
                          cicli.anio = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Tipo de Sangre: ");
                          cicli.tiposangre = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Size de Bicicleta: ");
                          cicli.sizebici = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Size de Uniforme: ");
                          cicli.sizeuniforme = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Telefono: ");
                          cicli.telefono = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Celular: ");
                          cicli.celular = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Email: ");
                          cicli.email = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese la Direccion: ");
                          cicli.direccion = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese una Persona de Contacto: ");
                          cicli.percontacto = Console.ReadLine();
                          Console.Write("Ingrese el Telefono del Contacto: ");
                          cicli.telecontacto = Console.ReadLine();
                          mC.agregarCiclistas(cicli);
                          Console.Clear();


                        break;

                        case "2": 

                            if(mC.totalciclis() > 0)
                            {
                             Console.Clear();
                             Console.WriteLine("Ciclistas agregados");
                             All = mC.obtenerCiclistas(); 
                             Console.WriteLine();

                             int n1 = 1;
                             foreach(Ciclista ciclis in All){


                                 Console.WriteLine(n1+"-"+ciclis.nombre);
                                 n1++;

                                }
                                Console.WriteLine();

                                Console.Write("Ingrese el numero del ciclista que desea modificar: ");
                                int n = 0;
                                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);

                                if(n <= mC.totalciclis()){

                                    mC.borrarCiclistas(n-1);
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    Ciclista ciclit = new Ciclista();
                                    Console.Clear();

                                    Console.WriteLine("Introducir nuevos datos de Ciclista");
                                    Console.WriteLine();

                                    Console.Write("Ingrese la Cedula: ");
                                    ciclit.cedula = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Nombre: ");
                                    ciclit.nombre = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Apellido: ");
                                    ciclit.apellido = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese su Dia de nacimiento: ");
                                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ciclit.dia);
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese su Mes de nacimiento: ");
                                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out ciclit.mes);
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese su Anio de nacimiento: ");
                                    ciclit.anio = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Tipo de Sangre: ");
                                    ciclit.tiposangre = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Size de Bicicleta: ");
                                    ciclit.sizebici = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Size de Uniforme: ");
                                    ciclit.sizeuniforme = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Telefono: ");
                                    ciclit.telefono = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Celular: ");
                                    ciclit.celular = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Email: ");
                                    ciclit.email = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese la Direccion: ");
                                    ciclit.direccion = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese una Persona de Contacto: ");
                                    ciclit.percontacto = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Telefono del Contacto: ");
                                    ciclit.telecontacto = Console.ReadLine();
                                    mC.agregarCiclistas(ciclit);
                                    Console.Clear();


                                }else{
                                    Console.WriteLine();
                                    Console.Write("No existe el ciclista numero "+n);
                                    Console.ReadKey();
                                }

                            }else{
                                Console.WriteLine();
                                Console.Write("Necesita agregar almenos un Ciclista");
                                Console.ReadKey();
                                }



                        break;

                        case "3": 

                        if(mC.totalciclis() > 0)
                        {
                         Console.Clear();
                         Console.WriteLine("Ciclistas agregados");
                         All = mC.obtenerCiclistas(); 
                         Console.WriteLine();

                         int n1 = 1;
                         foreach(Ciclista ciclis in All){


                             Console.WriteLine(n1+"-"+ciclis.nombre);
                             n1++;

                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();

                            Console.Write("Ingrese el numero del ciclista que desea eliminar: ");
                            int n = 0;
                            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);

                            if(n <= mC.totalciclis()){
                              mC.borrarCiclistas(n-1);
                              Console.WriteLine();
                              Console.WriteLine("Ciclista Eliminado");
                              Console.ReadKey();

                            }else{
                                Console.WriteLine();
                                Console.Write("No existe el ciclista numero "+n);
                                Console.ReadKey();
                            }

                        }else{
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.Write("Necesita agregar almenos un Ciclista");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            }


                        break;

                        case "4": 

                           Console.WriteLine();

                           FileStream streamout = new FileStream("DatosCicli.dat", FileMode.Create);
                           BinaryFormatter formaterout = new BinaryFormatter();
                           formaterout.Serialize(streamout, mC);
                           streamout.Close();

                           Console.Clear();
                           contiprograma2 = false;

                        break;

                       default: 

                          Console.WriteLine();
                          Console.WriteLine(seleccion + " No es una opcion de seleccion");
                          Console.ReadKey();

                        break;


                    }




                }

             break;

             case "2": 

                  bool contiprograma3 = true;

                  while(contiprograma3){

                      Console.Clear();
                      Console.WriteLine("Gestion de Actividades");
                      Console.WriteLine();
                      Console.WriteLine("1. Agregar Actividad");
                      Console.WriteLine("2. Volver a Menu Principal ");
                      Console.WriteLine();

                      Console.Write("Seleccione la opcion deseada: ");
                      seleccion = Console.ReadLine();

                      switch(seleccion){




case "1": 

                               Console.Clear();
                               Console.WriteLine("Ciclistas agregados");
                               All = mC.obtenerCiclistas(); 
                               Console.WriteLine();

                               int n1 = 1;
                               foreach(Ciclista ciclis in All){


                                   Console.WriteLine(n1+"-"+ciclis.nombre);
                                   n1++;

                                }
                                Console.WriteLine();

                                Console.Write("Ingrese el numero del ciclista que desea agregar actividad: ");
                                int n = 0;
                                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);

                                    Actividad acti = new Actividad();
                                    Ciclista cicli = new Ciclista();

                                    All = mC.obtenerCiclistas(); 
                                    Console.Clear();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Nombre del Ciclista: ");
                                    acti.ciclista = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese la Fecha de Actividad: ");
                                    acti.fechaact = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese la Distancia: ");
                                    acti.distancia = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese el Lugar de la Activiad: ");
                                    acti.lugar = Console.ReadLine();
                                    Console.Write("Ingrese la Dificultad de la Actividad: ");
                                    acti.dificultad = Console.ReadLine();
                                    mA.agregarActividades(acti);
                                    Console.Clear();






                          break; 
**This is bold**

                          case "2": 

                           Console.WriteLine();
                           FileStream streamout = new FileStream("DatosACT.dat", FileMode.Create);
                           BinaryFormatter formaterout = new BinaryFormatter();
                           formaterout.Serialize(streamout, mA);
                           streamout.Close();

                           Console.Clear();
                           contiprograma3 = false;

                          break;

                          default: 

                              Console.WriteLine();
                              Console.WriteLine(seleccion + " No es una opcion de seleccion");
                              Console.ReadKey();

                           break;


                        }


                    }

             break;

             case"3": 

             bool contiprograma4 = true;

             while(contiprograma4){

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Gestion de Reportes");
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("1. Listado de Ciclistas");
                    Console.WriteLine("2. Listado de Actividades");
                    Console.WriteLine("3. Listado de Ciclistas con Signo Zodiacal");
                    Console.WriteLine("4. Exportar Ciclista");
                    Console.WriteLine("5. Volver al Menu Principal");
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    Console.Write("Seleccione la opcion deseada: ");
                    seleccion = Console.ReadLine();

                    switch(seleccion){

                        case "1": 

                         Console.Clear();
                         Console.WriteLine("Lista de Ciclistas");
                         All = mC.obtenerCiclistas(); 
                         Console.WriteLine();

                         int n1 = 1;
                         foreach(Ciclista ciclis in All){


                             Console.WriteLine(n1+"-"+ciclis.nombre);
                             n1++;

                            }
                            Console.ReadKey();


                        break;

                        case "2":

                         Console.Clear();
                         Console.WriteLine("Lista de Actividades");
                         todo = mA.obtenerActividades(); 
                         Console.WriteLine();

                          n1 = 1;
                         foreach(Actividad actis in todo){


                             Console.WriteLine(n1+"-"+actis.lugar);
                             n1++;

                            }
                            Console.ReadKey();




                        break;

                        case "3": 

                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("Signos Zodiacales de los Ciclistas");
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        All = mC.obtenerCiclistas();



                        for(int z = 0; z < All.Count; z++ ){

                            switch(All[z].mes){

                              case 1:
                              if(All[z].dia >= 20)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Acuario");
                              else 
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Capricornio");
                              break;

                              case 2:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 18)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Acuario");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Piscis");
                              break;

                              case 3:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 20)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Piscis");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Aries");
                              break;

                              case 4:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 20)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Aries");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Tauro");
                              break;

                              case 5:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 20)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Tauro");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Geminis");
                              break;

                              case 6:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 20)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Geminis");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Cancer");
                              break;

                              case 7:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 21)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Cancer");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Leo");
                              break;

                              case 8: 
                              if(All[z].dia <= 21)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Leo");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Virgo");
                              break;

                              case 9:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 22)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Vrigo");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Libra");
                              break;

                              case 10: 
                              if(All[z].dia <= 22)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Libra");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Escorpio");
                              break;

                              case 11:
                              if(All[z].dia <= 22)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Escorpio");
                              else 
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Sagitario");
                              break;

                              case 12:  
                              if(All[z].dia <= 20)
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Sagitario");
                              else
                                Console.Write("El signo Zodiacal de "+All[z].nombre+" es Capricornio");
                              break;

                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                            Console.WriteLine();

                        }

                        Console.ReadKey();




                        break;
                        **This is bold**
                        case "4": 

                          string carpeta = "C:\\FELIZ";
                          if (Directory.Exists(carpeta) == false){
                            Directory.CreateDirectory(carpeta);

                          }


                         Console.Clear();
                         Console.WriteLine("Exportar Ciclistas");
                         All = mC.obtenerCiclistas();
                         todo = mA.obtenerActividades();


                         Console.WriteLine();

                          n1 = 1;
                         foreach(Ciclista ciclis in All){


                             Console.WriteLine(n1+"-"+ciclis.nombre);
                             n1++;

                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();

                            Console.Write("Ingrese el numero del ciclista que desea Exportar: ");
                            int n = 0;
                            int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n);

                            n1 = 1;

                             if(n <= mC.totalciclis()){
                                  for(int x = 0; x < All.Count; x++){
                                     string informacion = "<html>"+
                                     "<head>"+
                                     "</head>"+
                                     "<body style>"+
                                     "<table border='1'><tr><th>Cedula</th><td>"+All[x].cedula+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Nombre</th><td>"+All[x].nombre+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Apellido</th><td>"+All[x].apellido+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>FechaNacimiento</th><td>"+All[x].dia+All[x].mes+All[x].anio+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>TipoSangre</th><td>"+All[x].tiposangre+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>SizeBicicleta</th><td>"+All[x].sizebici+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>SizeUniforme</th><td>"+All[x].sizeuniforme+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Telefono</th><td>"+All[x].telefono+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Celular</th><td>"+All[x].celular+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Email</th><td>"+All[x].email+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Direccion</th><td>"+All[x].direccion+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>PersonaContacto</th><td>"+All[x].percontacto+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>TelefonoContacto</th><td>"+All[x].telecontacto+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>Ciclista</th><td>"+todo[x].ciclista+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>FechaActividad</th><td>"+todo[x].fechaact+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>DistanciaActividad</th><td>"+todo[x].distancia+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>LugarActividad</th><td>"+todo[x].lugar+
                                     "</td></tr><tr><th>DificultadActividad</th><td>"+todo[x].dificultad+
                                     "</td></tr></table></body>";

                                      File.WriteAllText("c:\\FELIZ\\"+All[x].cedula+".html", informacion);
                                    }

                                }else{
                                 Console.WriteLine();
                                 Console.Write("No existe el ciclista numero "+n);
                                 Console.ReadKey();
                                }





                        break;


                        case "5": 

                        Console.Clear();
                        contiprograma4 = false;

                        break;


                        default: 

                          Console.WriteLine();
                          Console.WriteLine(seleccion + " No es una opcion de seleccion");
                          Console.ReadKey();

                        break;



                    }



                }

             break;

             case "4": 

                 Console.WriteLine();
                 Console.Write("Vuelva pronto");
                 Console.ReadKey();
                 contiprograma = false;

             break;

             default: 

                   Console.WriteLine();
                   Console.WriteLine(seleccion + " No es una opcion de seleccion");
                   Console.ReadKey();



             break;





            }



        }



    }
}
```

Aquí esta el código de los datos de los ciclistas y actividades que están instanciados en el principal.

```
[Serializable]
public class Ciclista{

    public string cedula;
    public string nombre;
    public string apellido;
    public int dia;
    public int mes;
    public string anio;
    public string tiposangre;
    public string sizebici;
    public string sizeuniforme;
    public string telefono;
    public string celular;
    public string email;
    public string direccion;
    public string percontacto;
    public string telecontacto;

}

[Serializable]
public class manejadorCiclistas{

    private List<Ciclista> All = new List<Ciclista>();

    public void agregarCiclistas(Ciclista cicli){
        All.Add(cicli);

    }

    public int totalciclis(){
        return All.Count;

    }


    public void borrarCiclistas(int n1){
        All.RemoveAt(n1);

    }

    public List<Ciclista> obtenerCiclistas(){

        return All;
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Actividad{

    public string ciclista;
    public string fechaact;
    public string distancia;
    public string lugar;
    public string dificultad;
}

[Serializable]
public class manejadorActividades{

    private List<Actividad> todo = new List<Actividad>();

    public void agregarActividades(Actividad acti){
        todo.Add(acti);

    }

    public int totalactis(){
        return todo.Count;

    }

    public List<Actividad> obtenerActividades(){

        return todo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Para relacionar ciclistas y actividades basta con agregar una nueva propiedad a la clase Ciclista la cual almacena una lista de Actividades, para que quede algo como `ciclit.Actividades.add(Acti)` de esa forma cada objeto referente a un ciclista va a almacenas su propia lista de actividades, en vez de tener las listas por aparte. En la clase Ciclista y después de crear la clase Actividad agrega la nuevo propiedad `public List<Actividad> actividades`

Comment: No he entendido totalmente, creo otra clase actividades en ciclistas?

Comment: Sí, después de crear la clase Actividades, puede crear la clase Ciclista y como propiedad dentro de la clase Ciclista puede agregar una de esta forma `public List<Actividad> actividades` ésta propiedad le permitirá agregar una a una las actividades de cada ciclista, almacenando así una lista de objetos de tipo Actividades